# How to use a bash command as a custom shortcut?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, touchpad

I have a command to turn on/off a touchpad (that works in terminal):

```bash
param_name=TouchpadOff; touchpadoff_value=$(synclient -l | awk -v param_name=$param_name '$1==param_name {print $(NF)}'); (( tmp_value =  $touchpadoff_value - 1 )); synclient TouchpadOff=${tmp_value#-}
```

and I'd like to set it as a custom shortcut.

I tried to use `sh -c`:

```bash
sh -c "param_name=TouchpadOff; touchpadoff_value=$(synclient -l | awk -v param_name=$param_name '$1==param_name {print $(NF)}'); (( tmp_value =  $touchpadoff_value - 1 )); synclient TouchpadOff=${tmp_value#-}"
```

but it still didn't work properly - it was able to only turn on the touchpad.

I was also trying to add quoting marks for variables (`"$param_name"`) but it changed nothing.

Where am I mistaken?
I'd like not to create any script containing the command.

Comment: `sh` is a link to `/bin/dash`, a simpler shell which doesn't understand the `$(...)` construction. Use `bash -c ...`.

Comment: That is the point! You should have delivered this as a solution!

Comment: `dash` understands `$(...)` just fine - it's [part of the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). It's the bare arithmetic expression `((...))` that's the problem.

Comment: Ye, `bash -c` hasn't worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to debug the command, so I created a script containing it, made it executable (`chmod +x script.sh`) and run debugging mode: `sh -x script.sh`.

I got:

```
+ param_name=TouchpadOff
+ synclient -l
+ awk -v param_name=TouchpadOff $1==param_name {print $(NF)}
+ touchpadoff_value=1
+ tmp_value = 1 - 1
mmm: 1: tmp_value: not found
+ synclient TouchpadOff=
```

and noticed the mathematical expression is a problem here.

So, I replaced it (`(( tmp_value =  $touchpadoff_value - 1 ))`) with `let tmp_value=$touchpadoff_value-1`.

Unfortunately, `let` doesn't work with `sh` and I used `bash`, and here is my working solution I pasted as the custom shortcut's command:

```bash
bash -c "param=TouchpadOff; touchpadoff_value=$(synclient -l | awk -v param_name=$param '$1==param_name {print $(NF)}'); let tmp_value=$touchpadoff_value-1; synclient TouchpadOff=${tmp_value#-}"
```

Comment: I tried the original commands (put one command per line to the file `q.sh`) in order to try out `bash -x ./q.sh`. The debug output showed me that `TouchpadOff` toggles its value between 0 and 1 and the touchpad toggles between enabled and disabled. Replacing the original line was not necessary. - Your solution was helpful for me because I could learn from it how to debug a script. The post taught me doing arithmetic enclosing expressions in in double parentheses like `(( <arith. expr.> ))`.

Comment: You don't really need shell arithmetic here at all, just let awk do it for you i.e. print `$NF - 1` instead of `$NF`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make an alias.
Do:
man alias
to get helping the exact way.
They are probably in:
/home/[user]/.bashrc
There is probably a complex example.
An easy one is:
alias ll='ls -alF'

Comment: and in the shortcut as       bash -i -c "ll"